# Cross browser xml element selectors?

Tags: jquery, xml, cross-browser

Given an HTML document containing an xml element, something like this:

```
<xml><Test><Thing></Thing></Test></xml>​
```

Is there any good cross-browser solution to select elements out of there?

I would have thought that some simple jQuery would have worked, like the following:

```
$("xml Test Thing")
```

It works fine on Chrome, but doesn't find anything in IE 9.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hnztj/

Some background: I've got an older page that only works in IE. It bakes some XML into the document server-side, and then uses ActiveX controls to extract information from the XML. I'm trying to make it work in Chrome. Tweaking things to use jQuery works great on Chrome, but now IE doesn't work. BOO.

Comment: "Given an HTML document containing an xml element" — That isn't an HTML document, it is an invalid document.

Comment: You can make it work with `document.createElement("invalidtagnam")`, such as `document.createElement("Test");` however that won't make it valid and it still may not work in all situations such as cloning.

Comment: Dang. This thing may be stuck in IE land for a lot longer